# cocos2d-x fill circle with color and unable 50% opacity (for transparent effect)

Tags: cocos2d-x

Hello im trying to fill primitive circle with color , and then set the color opacity to 50% transparent .
i searched the net and haven't found any solution only cocos2d-iphone stuff .
i created inherited from sprite
and it does paint me circle .

```
void CircleSprite::draw(void)
{

 glLineWidth(2);
 cocos2d::ccDrawColor4B(0, 255, 255, 255);
 cocos2d::ccDrawCircle( ccp(100/2, 100/2), 50, CC_DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(90), 50, false);

}

#ifndef __CIRCLESPRITE_H__
#define __CIRCLESPRITE_H__

#include "cocos2d.h" 

class CircleSprite : public cocos2d::CCSprite
{
    public :
        virtual void draw(void);
    private:

};

#endif

in the main loop :
CCSize winSize = CCDirector::sharedDirector()->getWinSize();
        CCSprite* cloud = drowCloud();
        cloud->setPosition(ccp(cloud->getContentSize().width/2,winSize.height/2));
        this->addChild(cloud);

CCSprite* HelloWorld::drowCloud()
{
    CCSprite * pCloud = new CircleSprite();
    return pCloud;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

before:

*this->addChild(cloud);*

just add the line:

**cloud->setOpacity(128);**

the opacity value is from 0 to 255

Cheers,
Adriano

Answer (score 0):

For all sorts of custom drawing better use `DrawNode`, but unfortunatelly, basic DrawNode can't handle opacity by itself (this feature is in the plan for cocos2d-4.*). So if class AlphaNode inherite from DrawNode we can define setOpacity like this (tested at cocos2dx-3-13):

```
void AlphaNode::setOpacity(GLubyte opac) {
    mOpacity = opac;
    if (_bufferCount) {
        for (int i = 0; i < _bufferCount; i++) {
            _buffer[i].colors.a = mOpacity;
        }
    }

    if (_bufferCountGLPoint) {
        for (int i = 0; i < _bufferCountGLPoint; i++) {
            _bufferGLPoint[i].colors.a = mOpacity;
        }
    }

    if (_bufferCountGLLine) {
        for (int i = 0; i < _bufferCountGLLine; i++) {
            _bufferGLLine[i].colors.a = mOpacity;
        }
        _dirtyGLLine = true;
    }
    _dirty = true;
}
```

Better check this one for performance on target platform before use in production, since its "unauthorise" solution.

Ah, eah, for drawing circles there are methods `drawSolidCircle` and `drawCircle`.